# Under which conditions does small uniform norm imply 'similarity' of subgradients.

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be the set of proper convex functions functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$, where $X$ is a open and convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. I was wondering under which conditions on $\mathcal{S}$ we have 
\begin{gather}
\forall \epsilon>0\  \exists \delta>0 \text{ such that for } f,h \in \mathcal{S} ,\  ||f-h||_{\infty} < \delta \\
\Rightarrow \underset{ x \in X}{\sup} \underset{ v \in \partial f(x), w \in \partial h(x)}{\sup}||v-w||_2 <\epsilon 
\end{gather}

**Motivation**: Intuitively, the fact that $||f-h||_{\infty}$ is small, means that the shape of the graphs of the functions are similar  and hence also their suporting hyperplanes might be similar. Of course this is just a picture that  I have in mind for the 1-dimensional case.

Any help or suggestions for possible references to similar results would be great.

**From where the problemm comes**: I have a function $F$ that maps convex functions to elements of their subgradient at any given point. I would like to show that if the mapped functions are similar, i.e. $||f-h||_{\infty}$ is sufficiently small, then we can say that $||F(h)-F(f)||_{2}$ is small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming any conditions on $S$ if $S$ still contains at least one non-smooth function then your claim does not hold.

**Proof**:  Let $f \in S$ such that $f$ is not differentiable at $x_0 \in X.$ Hence there exist $v , w \in \partial f(x_0) $ such that $ v \neq w $. Set $ \epsilon = \| v -w \| $
Then observe that for any positive delta , your statement does not holds for two functions $f,~ h$ where $ f = h $ and $v \in \partial f(x_0) $ and $ w \in \partial h(x_0) $.

P.S:
But I feel like your claim would be true if you switch the second $\sup$ to $\inf$.

Comment: I found this ( https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976913/hausdorff-distance-between-subdifferential-sets?rq=1). Hence, there exists a notion of convergence of function which guarantees that the subdifferentials converge in some sense, but I have to give it a look.

Comment: are you confident that the result holds if we switch $\sup$ with $\inf$. Do you have an idea how to prove that?

Comment: @sigmatau I'm not 100 % sure about. I just guessed , that's what my intuition tells me. I need to pick up pen I spend time to prove it (or reject it). I suggest you write a separate question for that.

Comment: Already did it today https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3004735/a-condition-for-similarity-of-subgradients-of-convex-proper-functions . Thank you for your help. .